# Verifying injection of an isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

> Suppose $n$ and $r$ are coprime and define a map $\phi: \mathbb{Z}_n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_n$ which sends $x \mapsto rx$. Show $\phi$ is an isomorphism.

I verified ontoness and the operation preserving property of $\phi$. I'm getting stuck with 1-1 though. My computation:

$$ \phi(a) = \phi(b) \text{ mod }n \\
ra = rb\text{ mod }n \\
r(a-b) = 0 \text{ mod }n \\
\text{Note: }\gcd(r,n)=1 \text{ so } r \neq 0\text{. Thus} \\
(a-b) = 0 \text{ mod }n \\
a=b \text{ mod }n
$$

Apparently this reasoning is not correct.

1. What went wrong?
2. How do I argue correctly?

Comment: where do you think is the fault?

Comment: What do you mean by $U(n)$? This looks to me like the $n$-dimensional unitary group, in which case this doesn't make any sense. (Also note that in the notation you're using "$n$" to mean two different things, in "$n\mapsto rn$" and "$\Bbb Z_n$".)

Comment: @janmarqz I don't know that's why I'm asking! I think the gcd -- but I have no reason to suppose this. It won't be zero because 0 and $n$ aren't coprime. I have reason to believe its incorrect because it was marked incorrect on my homework and I'm trying to understand it.

Comment: @David C Ulrich Okay fixed notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have first to check that the map is well-defined, that is, if $x\equiv y\pmod{n}$, then $rx\equiv ry\pmod{n}$. This is essentially obvious, but should be pointed out.

The homomorphism property is obvious as well, so let's do injectivity: if $\phi(x)=0$, then $rx\equiv0\pmod{n}$. As $r$ and $n$ are coprime, there are $a$ and $b$ so that $ar+bn=1$, so from $rx=kn$, we also have
$$
arx=akn
$$
and so
$$
x=1x=(ar+bn)x=arx+bnx=akn+bnx=(ak+bx)n
$$
Hence $x\equiv0\pmod{n}$. You don't need to prove surjectivity.

Note that the simple fact that $r\not\equiv0\pmod n$ doesn't allow you to conclude $a-b=0$ from $r(a-b)=0$. For instance, $3\not\equiv0\pmod6$,  $3(4-2)\equiv0\pmod{6}$, but $4-2\not\equiv0\pmod{6}$.

The key fact is that $r$ and $n$ being coprime implies there is *an inverse* of $r$ modulo $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $r^{-1}$ exists and $ra\equiv rb\mod n$ is a congruence, this mean that $r^{-1}ra\equiv r^{-1}rb\mod n$, then $a\equiv b\mod n$.

Comment: I understand this, thanks! why doesn't the reasoning above work though?

Comment: being coprime implies that $1=r t+ns$ for some $t,s$ and $\mod n$ you get $rt\equiv 1$

Comment: @yoshi The problem is where you say (essentially) that since $r\ne0$ you can divide by $r$. You _can_ divide by $r$, but in this context that doesn't follow just because $r\ne 0$.